# There is no "display_url" and "video_url" in the jason object of instagram post

Tags: android, url, android-volley, instagram

I'm trying to make an app that can download posts from Instagram (photo, reels, and IGTV).

I'm referring to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkEQ0SmF3bY) for making the app

I'm a newbie in downloading a file from a URL or API

when I convert the Instagram URL to Jason object, I want to find 2 parameters "display_url" and "video_url" but I don't know probably the parameters are removed and I'm not able to download the image or video

> those who don't know
>
> https://www.instagram.com/p/CcjyBsquX89/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link
>
> now just remove `utm_source=ig_web_copy_link` part and add `__a=1`
> after `/?`
>
> and u will get the Jason object

instead of there being multiple versions of the resolution of a particular image or video and all the resolution URLs are named as the same "url" parameters there is no differentiating factor

how can I download the files now?

I want to download the highest resolution file but as all the resolution has named the same "url" I'm not able to download

before that, if we consider the youtube video(mentioned above ) there is both "display_url" for the image and "video_url" for the video so the guy in the video can easily add the exact parameters in the model class

Comment: Did you find any solution?I need to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `/?__a=1&__d=dis` instead of this `/?__a=1`.